# Unicode Base64 values in a LDAP Filter

Tags: unicode, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I'm trying to find Active Directory users who are:

```
memberOf::Q049RG9tw6RuZW4tQWRtaW5zLENOPVVzZXJzLERDPXh4eCxEQz1pbnRlcm4=
```

(this base64 stands for `CN=Domänen-Admins,CN=Users,DC=xxx,DC=intern`)

Searching for it directly (via API or ldapsearch) yields no result (since it's a unicode DN):

```
ldapsearch -h ... -D Administrator@xxx.intern -x -w '...' -b dc=xxx,dc=intern '(memberof=CN=Domänen-Benutzer,CN=Users,DC=xxx,DC=intern)'
```

Following filters didn't work either:

```
(memberof=Q049RG9tw6RuZW4tQWRtaW5zLENOPVVzZXJzLERDPXh4eCxEQz1pbnRlcm4=)
(memberof=:Q049RG9tw6RuZW4tQWRtaW5zLENOPVVzZXJzLERDPXh4eCxEQz1pbnRlcm4=)
(memberof=::Q049RG9tw6RuZW4tQWRtaW5zLENOPVVzZXJzLERDPXh4eCxEQz1pbnRlcm4=)
```

I can't find any documentation except for RFC specifying base64 encoding in LDIF files.

**UPDATE** the above ldapsearch commands are for convenience only, it doesn't work with LDAP API either - using:

```
ldap.search_s('dc=xxx,dc=intern', ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, filter, ['cn'])
```

with filters:

```
filter='(memberof=CN=Domänen-Benutzer,CN=Users,DC=xxx,DC=intern)'.encode('utf-8') # raw UTF
filter='(memberof=CN=Domänen-Benutzer,CN=Users,DC=xxx,DC=intern)'.encode('cp1252') # raw 1252
filter=b'(memberof=CN=Dom\\e4nen-Benutzer,CN=Users,DC=xxx,DC=intern)' # hex
filter=b'(memberof=CN=Dom\\xe4nen-Benutzer,CN=Users,DC=xxx,DC=intern)' # python repr
```

I've also confirmed with Wireshark that the filter is indeed transmitted in UTF8

Answer (score 2):

The attribute type `cn` has a Directory String syntax according to the standard. Directory Strings are encoded using UTF-8. Saying that searching via API yields no results incorrect. You are just using the incorrect encoding. The `ldapsearch` tool (assuming you are using OpenLDAP) may not support searching with accented characters.

The `ldapsearch` utility shipped with the [UnboundID Data Store](https://www.unboundid.com/product/data-store) handles this pretty well. Here is the LDIF that I used for testing:

```
dn:: Q049RG9tw4PCpG5lbi1BZG1pbnMsZGM9ZXhhbXBsZSxkYz1jb20=
objectclass: organizationalPerson
sn: person

dn: cn=mygroup,dc=example,dc=com
objectclass: groupofnames
member:: Q049RG9tw4PCpG5lbi1BZG1pbnMsZGM9ZXhhbXBsZSxkYz1jb20=
```

Here is my command line test:

```
$ ldapsearch -b "dc=example,dc=com" "member=CN=DomÃ¤nen-Admins,dc=example,dc=com"
dn: cn=mygroup,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: groupofnames
cn: mygroup
member:: Q049RG9tw4PCpG5lbi1BZG1pbnMsZGM9ZXhhbXBsZSxkYz1jb20=
```

Also, you may want to read the [Directory String syntax from RFC 4517](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4517#section-3.3.6).

**UPDATE**

I managed to make this working with Active Directory (Windows Server 2012 R2, DataCenter edition) and using the `ldapsearch` utility shipped with the UnboundID Data Store. This is what I see:

```
$ ldapsearch --trustAll -Z -h <hostname> -p 636 -D "cn=administrator,cn=users,dc=dom-ad2,dc=local" -w <password> -b "cn=test,dc=dom-ad2,dc=local" "member=CN=DomÃ¤nen-Benutzer,CN=test,DC=dom-ad2,DC=local"

dn: CN=mygroup,CN=test,DC=dom-ad2,DC=local
objectClass: top
objectClass: group
cn: mygroup
member:: Q049RG9tw4PCpG5lbi1CZW51dHplcixDTj10ZXN0LERDPWRvbS1hZDIsREM9bG9jYWw=
member: CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=dom-ad2,DC=local
distinguishedName: CN=mygroup,CN=test,DC=dom-ad2,DC=local
instanceType: 4
whenCreated: 20160514104531.0Z
```

You can also use the `LDAPSearch` example class from the UnboundID LDAP SDK (jar download [link](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/unboundid/unboundid-ldapsdk/3.1.1/unboundid-ldapsdk-3.1.1.jar)) to accomplish this. Here is the equivalent command-line I used with the LDAP SDK:

```
$ java -cp unboundid-ldapsdk-3.1.1.jar com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.examples.LDAPSearch --trustAll -Z -h <host> -p 636 -D "cn=administrator,cn=users,dc=dom-ad2,dc=local" -w <password> -b "cn=test,dc=dom-ad2,dc=local" "member=CN=DomÃ¤nen-Benutzer,CN=test,DC=dom-ad2,DC=local"
```

Comment: See my updates as well. It works for me with a different client.

Comment: I've tried this and it indeed works with the ``member=`` filter. Unfortunately what I need is ``memberof=`` and it returns no results.

Comment: However I've noted that this only happens for the system groups like "Users" and "Domain admins". User-created groups handle memberOf just fine!

Comment: Built-in groups won't show up in `memberOf`. You are better off searching the other way around (search the member attribute of the group for the user). I just answered [another questions about that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241296/ldap-dn-search-memberof). With that special filter syntax, it will search nested groups too.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to use the base64 encoded value? You must base64 decode the value before using it in a LDAP filter. It either needs to be the string representation name of the value or a hex escaped version of the string value when used in a LDAP filter.

**Edit:** After translating the group names a bit from your question it became more apparent to me what your issue actually is. The default "Domain Users" group is actually a primary group for a user. It will not show up in the `memberOf` list (hence the empty results on a search). To check if a user is a member of "Domain Users" you must inspect the `primaryGroupId` value for a user. In 99% of all cases this will always be the default "Domain Users" group.

Comment: Please see the updated question. AD returns no results for a "normal" filter with unicode characters. Hex does not help.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that it's only impossible to fetch members for built-in AD groups (i.e. `(isCriticalSystemObject=TRUE)`). `memberOf` queries for user-created groups work just fine, independently from encoding used. No hex encoding was necessary.

Comment: Specifically what builtin groups? Remember that a group like "Domain Users" isn't actually a group that will show up in the `memberOf` backlink. It actually shows up in the `primaryGroupId` attribute (and in a form that you must decode/parse to interpret, as you really only get the RID of the group, not the name).