# LDAP DN search memberof

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

Currently I'm trying to determine if a user should be able to login using LDAP. I've read up on many LDAP connections written in PHP and so far things were on track until I wanted to search if a user was part of a certain group.

**Details I currently have to connecto to the LDAP server:**

- DN: CN=PAY LDAP user,OU=pay,OU=Applications,OU=IT
  Specials,DC=domain,DC=be
- SAM: admin
- PWD: password
- Search DN ADM: OU=OU GROUP,OU=AD,DC=domain,DC=be
- LDAP / GC server: knt-adm-dc1.domain.be, knt-adm-dc2.domain.be

This code though doesn't return me any results:

```
if($bind = ldap_bind($ldap, $username, $password)) {
    $filter = "(samaccountname=".$user.")";
    $attr = array("memberof");
    $result = ldap_search($ldap, $ldap_dn, $filter, $attr) or exit("Unable to search LDAP server");
    $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
    ldap_unbind($ldap);
}
```

When I leave out the $attr from the search I do get a result though I can't seem to find a way to determine of this user is part of the ADMIN group.

From what I could read online the memberof attribute should be used to find if a user is part of a group though.

Comment: There are two ways you can approach this: either read the `memberof` attribute on the user itself or read the `member` attribute on the group. Note that built-in groups may behave differently fro user-defined ones.
Also - make sure that the user that your binding as have privileges to read this attribute. You can easily test if this is an access control issue if you have the administrator credentials.

Comment: Seems that there is no memberof attribute on the user as far as I can see. Whenever I search for the memberof attribute nothing is returned.

Comment: Have you tried searching as administrator? Have you tried inspecting the entry using a tool like ldp.exe?

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

1. If a user is not a member of any groups, the `memberOf` attribute will not exist.
2. Builtin groups do not show up in the `memberOf` attribute.

A more failure-proof method is to use a somewhat obscure LDAP filter to search your group, and any nested groups, for a user: the LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN rule. Details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx).

In PHP, it would look something like this (untested):

```
$filter = "(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=".$user_distinguished_name.")";
$ldap_dn = "LDAP://".$group_distinguished_name;
$attr = array("cn");
$result = ldap_list($ldap, $ldap_dn, $filter, $attr);
```

Where `$user_distinguished_name` is the distinguished name of the user, and `$group_distinguished_name` is the DN of the group. You may have to get those beforehand.

Note I'm put [ldap_list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-list.php) instead of [ldap_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php). The only difference between the two is the scope of the search. I think ldap_search might still work, but it's not needed.